# Handler to grab variable values from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I have so far

```
//file uploader 
///////////////////////////
function uploader(){
    var file = $(this).val()
    var error = $(this).next('.req-error')
    var fileLimit = $(this).attr('maxlength')-1
    var uploadedFiles = $(this).siblings('.uploaded-file').length 

    //make uploaded file label
    if(error.length ==1){
        $(this).next().after('<div class="uploaded-file"><span>X</span>'+file+'</div>')
    }else {
        $(this).after('<div class="uploaded-file"><span>X</span>'+file+'</div>')
    }

    //count uploaded files
    if(uploadedFiles >= fileLimit ){
        $(this).attr('disabled', true)
    }else{
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled')
    } 

    //clear input field
    $(this).val('')
}; 
$(".input-file").change(uploader)

function removeFile(uploader){
    $(this).remove()

}
$('.uploaded-file').live('click',removeFile)
```

I made a limit for how many files can be uploaded. Once the limit is reached, the input gets disable but, when a file is removed I want it to enable again if its under the limit. Im just not sure how to get the removeFile function to read the if statement from the uploader function.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to have a counter that represents the number of files that have been uploaded. Place this in a var at the same level as both your uploader & removeFile functions:

```
var uploadedFiles = 0;

function uploader() {
    ...
}

function removeFile() {
    ...
}
```

Then increment/decrement this variable as you add/remove files.